# IndexOf in a function

Tags: javascript

How can I return the index position of `"needle"` in this array?

```js
function findNeedle(haystack) {
  return findNeedle.indexOf('needle');
}

findNeedle(['3', '123124234', undefined, 'needle', 'world', 'hay', 2, '3', true, false]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findNeedle` is the function, not the array that is passed as an argument of the function. Inside the function, `haystack` is your array.

```js
function findNeedle(haystack) {
  return haystack.indexOf('needle');
}

var result = findNeedle(['3', '123124234', undefined, 'needle', 'world', 'hay', 2, '3', true, false]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

make it

```
return haystack.indexOf('needle');
```

you need to use the argument you have passed to the function instead of the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

You shoudn't run method .indexOf() on function. Call it on your property `haystack` instead.

```
return haystack.indexOf('needle');
```